# Combo Box SQL Database connection not working

Tags: xamarin.android

I would like to inform you that I am using DevExpress Xamarin ComboBox but I cannot connect SQL Database. Can you please give me any idea how to connect with the Microsoft SQL server database? My code is mentioned below for your reference.

```
  sqlConnection.Open();
  SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("Select (R_Status) from Room_Status", sqlConnection);
  SqlDataReader reader;
  reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("R_Status", typeof(string));
  dt.Load(reader);
  CBRoomStatus.ValueMember = "R_Status";
  CBRoomStatus.ItemsSource = dt.de;
  sqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Was there any error message and can you debug to find which line didn't work? In addition, I recommend to use sqlite instead of the Microsoft SQL server database.

Comment: Dear support I Am using microsoft SQL database 2nd there is no any error show in the Combobox show only one record which is my last record of table it's not fill up even I use loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following code to check how many line record you get from the table.

```
  sqlConnection.Open();
  SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("Select (R_Status) from Room_Status", sqlConnection);
  SqlDataReader reader;
  reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
  var resource = new List<string>();
  while (reader.Read())
  { 
    resource.Add((string)reader["R_Status"]);
  }
  CBRoomStatus.ItemsSource = resource;
  sqlConnection.Close();
```

You can add a break point at the resource.Add() to check how many times have read.

Comment: Dear Liyun Zhang, thanks for your such nice support yes it's worked 100 %  today I am so happy because of you. you make me Smail on my face Relly you are the grate person thanks  a lot and GOD bless you GOD will give you a lot of thing to you what you want from him.